# Gulp: Read script tags from footer

Tags: gulp, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to accomplish the following with Gulp:

1. Read file `footer.html` and parse all the paths in `<script src="` tags - using `gulp-dom-src`;
2. Pipe those paths into `contact`;
3. `uglify` everything;

The last steps are easy, however I'm stuck with the first step. My current code is:

```
var domSrc = require("gulp-dom-src"),
concat      = require("gulp-concat"),
uglify      = require("gulp-uglify");

var footerFile = "Footer/View-en.html";

gulp.task("deploy", function(){
    domSrc({ file: footerFile, selector: "script", attribute: "src" })  
    .pipe(concat("script.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("Dist/Resources/"))
});
```

If I try to debug the pipe using `.pipe(debug({title: "pipe:"}));` it appears to be empty, any reason why? Any other recommended packages to accomplish the same?

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely reason is that you made a mistake in your HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same issue, it blowed my brain ))
so there is answer: you need to add `cwd:process.cwd()` in `domSrc` options, like this:

```
var options = { 
    cwd: process.cwd(), 
    file: footerFile, 
    selector: "script", 
    attribute: "src" 
};

domSrc(options);
```